# react.js with laravel relationship

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, react-native

this error happend when I add company name to client

{client.company.name} in view

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

what can I do to solve this error

in CompanyController

```
public function index(request $request)
    {

        $clients = $this->client->with('company')->orderBy('date_created','DESC');

        if($request->search){
            $clients = $clients->where(function($query) use($request){          
                $query->where('client_id', $request->search);
                $query->orWhere('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
                $query->orWhere('contact_phone',$request->search);
            });
        }
        // applay pagination on clients list
        $clients = $clients->paginate(10);
        // get all clients 
        return response()->json($clients);
    }
```

in view :

```
constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            loading : true,
            clients:[],
            search    : '',
            page      : 1,
            total     : 0,
            pageCount : 0,
        };
        this.handleChangeSearch   = this.handleChangeSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit         = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handlePageChange     = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
    }
```

in render()

```
<tbody>
     { 
        this.state.clients.map(function(client, i){
           return(
             <tr key={i}>
              <td><Link to={`/clients/${client.client_id}`}>{client.client_id}</Link></td>
              <td>{client.name }</td>
              <td>{client.email_address }</td>
              <td>{client.contact_phone }</td>
              <td>{client.date_created }</td>
              <td>{client.company.name}</td>
            </tr>);
          })
         }
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Did you check in your database? As I think you are getting wrong variable in you react render. Or try to print your value in console log.

Comment: it is correct .

Comment: Can you please show us your console log?

Comment: getting data from DB is async process so when view render may be it's return promises instead of actual data so you can use async wait function when getting data from DB for more info search async await in google