# Laravel React relation one to many

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I' trying to get the data from product table which includes the category_id (one to many relationship) in React but it returns

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I've the same problem like this [react.js with laravel relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608440/react-js-with-laravel-relationship). I've tried to get the data in blade.php and I got it but in react no. This is an example of what to make

```
    let products = JSON.parse(this.props.data);
    {products.map(product=>
              <tr key={product.id}>
                <td> <a>{product.name }</a> </td>
                <td>{product.brand} </td>
                <td>{product.category.name}</td>
           

     <td>{product.status} </td>
})
```

Comment: The category of product is likely not loaded, so `<td>{product.category.name}</td>` fails. Can you show some more code? Like the controller and where you get the products initially.

Comment: the products array contains the category_id which I want to fetch the category name from it as they are related with each other..which part of code you want me to show!

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into similar problem. I was able to solve it by returning the $product->category() along with $product.

```
  function getProduct($id) {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return [
        "product" => $product,
        "product_categories" => $product->productCategory,
    ];
  }
```

And to retrieve on the react frontend, do the following

```
const {product, product_category} = this.props.data
{products.map(product=>
          <tr key={product.id}>
            <td> <a>{product.name }</a> </td>
            <td>{product.brand} </td>
            <td>{product_category.name}</td>
            <td>{product.status} </td>
})
```